# Husband has a job offer, and we might move. How do I ask my manager for remote position?

Tags: resignation, manager, telecommute, relocation, remote-work

My husband was offered a new job within his company, which would start in October. It means we are moving a few states away, but only if I can work remotely.

It’s not a job that he applied for but something his manager recommended him for. It’s a great opportunity for him. My company has returned to the office but we have been working from home during the pandemic. I am hoping to stay on with my company but work remotely from the new state. When do I tell my manager my husband was offered a new job? I would like to give enough notice but also don’t want to be without a job until October if they decide to let me go.

If I am unable to work remotely, it may change our minds about my husband accepting the new job.

Comment: A good portion of this will come down to your company's ability to handle tax considerations in the new state. Once you become a resident of a new state, there is a limited amount of time your company can continue to pay you without paying proper state taxes in your new locale.

Comment: give exactly the notice stated on your contract, no more or less.

Comment: i've edited your Q to make it more concise. Please feel free to edit

Comment: @Megan, Does your company have a 2-week notice policy ? If yes, can you wait till September to turn in the notice ? Or does your company require a 3-month notice instead ? In the US, most companies have a 2-week notice policy.

Comment: I should’ve mentioned that before. I work for a large company with offices in every state (just not this particular town). There are many employees who work remotely, just not anyone on my team. 

My company has a standard 2 week notice policy.

Comment: @Megan - If other employees are working remotely you need to simply determine what the requirements are to work remotely.

Comment: @Job_September_2020 Companies don't have a 2 week notice policy-  the states have an employment at will policy.  Which means she has no legal minimum notice, anything she does give is a courtesy.  2 weeks is customary, but nobody needs to give them.

Answer (score 5):

Some of this depends on your relationship with your manager and on your corporate culture, but the way I'd approach it, with a manager who I had a good relationship with, would be:

> My husband is starting to look at some options for promotion at work, and some of those options might involve moving to another city.  I like it here and want to stay here, so I want to know what our company's policy will be regarding remote work, so we can evaluate our options.  If he were to need to move, are there circumstances in which I would be able to continue working here?

However, this assumes that this wouldn't be an entirely unheard of thing in your company.  If it would be, then you probably should go into this assuming the answer is no - and thus you have to pick, risk the company letting you go versus turning down the promotion.

Don't worry too much about "enough notice"; whatever is in your contract, or else 2 weeks or whatever is common in your industry, is plenty if you do have to resign.  Also, take into account the likelihood that you'd get a severance package if they did let you go (are you a short time, or long time, employee?) and the difficulty they would have in replacing you.  It's possible even if you got let go, that you're better off getting the severance package now and starting the job hunt in this really hot job market a bit early - would it be a big deal if you left a month or two early to the new location?

Answer (score 5):

You say that your husband's decision depends on (or potentially affected by) your ability to work remotely.

I suggest to share this information with your manager. It's not a done deal anyway, and you don't need to present it as such.

You can tell them that if it's not possible for them to have you work from another state then your husband will likely turn down his relocation.

If they agree - great. If they don't agree - just say that you understand, that it's ok, and that you were ambivalent about uprooting to another state anyway.

If, despite their refusal, you and your husband still decide to move - keep it to yourself and give them prior notice according to your contract with them.